# Kivy remove_widget removes all children widgets from the screen

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

I want to `remove` children widgets from my `RootWidget` in the example below, but clicking on the RootButton removes both of children widgets (both the RED and the GREEN one). However in the `self.children` list printed in the shell there is still the second child remaining, but not to see on the RootWidget. What am doing wrong here?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

RED = (1, 0, 0, 1)
GREEN = (0, 1, 0, 1)

class RootWidget(Button):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RootWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.add_widget(Button(background_color = RED), 0)
        self.add_widget(Button(background_color = GREEN), 1)
        self.bind(on_press = self.btn_call_back)

    def btn_call_back(self, v):
        try:
            print "_" * 60
            print self.children
            print "+" * 60
            self.remove_widget(self.children[0])
            print self.children
            print "_" * 60
        except IndexError:
            print "no children any more!"




class TutorApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TutorApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what's the exact reason of this behavior. Perhaps when you press your button and it replaces its background from `background_normal` to `background_down` this in some way override background of its children. This doesn't matter because you aren't really supposed to add widgets to a `Button` instance. Use `Widget` or some layout class instead to arrange your widgets.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<Widget>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: 0, 0, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
''')

RED = (1, 0, 0, 1)
GREEN = (0, 1, 0, 1)

class RootWidget(Widget):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RootWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.add_widget(Button(background_color = RED), 0)
        self.add_widget(Button(background_color = GREEN), 1)
        self.bind(on_touch_down = self.btn_call_back)


    def btn_call_back(self, *args):
        try:
            print "_" * 60
            print self.children
            print "+" * 60
            self.remove_widget(self.children[0])
            print self.children
            print "_" * 60
        except IndexError:
            print "no children any more!"


class TutorApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TutorApp().run()
```